# Get FATAL ERROR on include_once by switching to php 7.2.19

Tags: php, include

I switched to the last php 7.2.19 version and then I get Errors on includes as include_once where everything was ok before

> PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/xxx/domains/xxx.xxx/public_html/inc/smarty/libs/plugins/shared.make_timestamp.php'
>   for inclusion

The absolute path is correct and the file exists. How this can happen? For which reasons? Some others includes are ok, if I test the same path in other code, it works fine. Crazy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2.4. Include\_once don´t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423273/error-with-php-5-6-to-php-7-2-4-include-once-don%c2%b4t-work)

Comment: Not really, my path is absolute and it works with php 7.2.18